# Ng-click not working in div

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've got a menu that appears when I click on a button. Well, into that menu, I have pairs of spans: icon-title. Pretty straightforward, I guess.

Well, somehow, these spans don't call my controller method when I click on them. I tried wrapping these pairs in divs and setting the ng-click on them, but that does not work either.

This is my contextual menu:

```
<div class="opciones" ng-hide="optionsHide">
      <div>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock icono"></span> <span class="optionsLabel">Encrypt</span>
      </div><br>
      <div ng-click="removeNote()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash icono"></span><span class="optionsLabel">&nbspDelete</span><br>
      </div><br>
      <div>
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench icono"></span><span class="optionsLabel">&nbspOptions</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Currently, I'm only focused on the "removeNote()" function. I've got both angular and node methods ready to test, but I just can't use them since I can't perform the click.

This is the function, inside the working controller:

```
    $scope.removeNote = function(){
      $http.post('/removeNote', $scope.mainNote).success(function(data){
        console.log("Note removed");
        console.log(data);
        loadNotes();
        }).error(function(err){
          console.log("ERROR ON DELETE");
          console.log(err);
          });
    }
```

Why ng-click does not call this function? Am I missing something?

edit:

Controller declaration:

Upper controller:

```
 app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', 'focus', function($scope, $http, $filter, focus){
```

Inner:

```
app.controller('contentCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', '$timeout', function($scope, $q, $timeout) {
```

Use:

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-cloak>
    // Things
     <content ng-controller="contentCtrl">
     // My contextual menu as shown above
```

Actually, this method is inside another controller (yes, two nested controllers), but the rest of inherited functions work properly; the only one that is not working is this one. Anyways, I keep seeing the normal pointer when I put the mouse on my div/pair of spans, so it's not being applied at all (I can see it in the HTML console tho).

Comment: My first guess is that you're getting an error because "success" is spelled wrong in your $http.post callback.  Check your console log.

Comment: Just fixed and edited that typo, but thanks! That's not the problem anyways, since the method is never being called.

Comment: What does the declaration of your controller look like, and where is the controller set in your HTML? Thanks!

Comment: Inspect the div containing the ngClick directive and check that it covers the area where you are clicking. Depending on your css those divs can have 0 width and height or being displaced from where the span and icon are. If you put the directive inside the span does it work? if the ngClick doesn't work in the span then you may have a js error as @Rob suggest

Comment: Yes, it does cover the whole area. Btw, editted with more info!

Comment: Make us a plunkr (https://plnkr.co/)! Also, try attaching a regular onClick to the span to see if the element is even accepting the mouseclick event. Something could be 'covering' it.

Comment: Are you sure that function never called? Did you try to catch it with debugger, or put `console.log` befor `$http.post`?
try to empty your function...
Maybe it is in ng-repeat, and it has own scope?

Comment: @AntonTemchenko No, it's not being called, I already tested it.

Comment: @IanGabes I think it would be a mess, too much things here and there, gotta do tomorrow if it keeps this way tho!

Comment: @user6329397 Please post your nested controllers in the question. Otherwise, it's not answerable.

Comment: There you have it @Saad

Comment: @user6329397 Where is your `.opciones` class div in template? Inside of contentCtrl or outside of it? Also, in which controller `$scope.removeNote()` function is defined?

Comment: I already realised what's going on: the onBlur directive is messing this up. If I remove it, the function gets properly thrown. How can I do so I keep the ngBlur?

Comment: Where did you use `ng-blur`? If ng-blur is causing issue, use `ng-mousedown` instead of `ng-click`. i.e `ng-mousedown=removeNote()`

Comment: @Saad That fixed it! Post it as an answer and I will accept it!

Comment: @user6329397 Please add template code in question where you have used ng-blur so that others can understand what's going on. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try altering your ng-controller line:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
```

Then your method call:

```
<div ng-click="vm.removeNote()">
```

Does it work now, does the console.log give you something?